# GPS data from smartphone

Tags: localization, navigation, gps, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to add GPS data to my project in order to improve robot localization estimate.
I've read that some people did this successfully using an external GPS device.
However, I would like to do this by pulling the GPS data from a smartphone.

A few questions:

1. Does someone have already done this? I did some research but I couldn't find it.
2. How could I pull the GPS data from the smartphone?
3. Does the smartphone output the GPS data in the same format as a regular GPS device?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189818/gps-data-from-smartphone/) by [gerhenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19473/gerhenz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2014-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using an Android device, you might try the [android_sensors_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/android_sensors_driver) ([Google play link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ros.android.sensors_driver&hl=en)). This has worked relatively well for me in the past.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gerhenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19473/gerhenz/) on 2014-08-12**:
My intention was to use a Windows phone, but in case I don't manage to do it I will end up using an Android device. This package you mentioned seems really good, I will take a look. Thanks!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-12**:
ROS support for Windows phone is non-existent (afaik). You might be able to get one of the c# implementations to work on it, but it is probably going to take some effort.